# Ordering a DataTable in Descending Order using Multiple Columns C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable

I want to create a method which is able to take a Datatable and order the rows in descending order via multiple columns specified.

Below is an example of when I call the table sorting method:

```
t1 = getSortedTable(t1 , "Hotel Costs, Flight Cost DESC");
```

The Hotel Costs and Flight Costs are both type Double columns. The method for sorting is as below:

```
public static DataTable getSortedTable(DataTable dt, string sort)
    {
        DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
        newTable = dt.Clone();
        newTable.Rows.Clear();
        DataRow[] newRows = dt.Select("", sort);
        foreach (DataRow nr in newRows)
        {
            newTable.Rows.Add(nr.ItemArray);
        }
        return newTable;
    }
```

The method only returns a table with rows sorted via the Flight Cost in descending order.

Comment: Have you tried passing in `"Hotel Costs DESC, Flight Cost DESC"` - Note, the additional DESC

Comment: Yes, still get the same result!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the `DefaultView` with the sort parameters and just return that view `ToTable()`:

```
public static DataTable GetSortedTable(DataTable dt, string sort)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = sort;
    return dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
}
```

EDIT: There's a chance that having spaces in your column names will interfere with the sort so you can either rename your column names like so:

```
foreach(var column in dt.Columns)
{
    column.ColumnName = column.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
}
```

Or use linq

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x=>x.Field<decimal>("Hotel Costs")).ThenByDescending(x=>x.Field<decimal>("Flight Costs"))
    .Select(x=>x)
    .CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: That's how you sort on columns mate... although I've just notices you have spaces in the column names which will probably cause you trouble... try `"[Hotel Cost DESC],[Flight Costs DESC]"`

Comment: Hi @Sean T ,  "[Hotel Cost DESC],[Flight Costs DESC]" is still giving me the same result. Trying the linq method but it's throwing an error on the last x.Field<...> bit saying "x does not exist in the current context".

Comment: tbf you may not need the `.Select()` part... I can't recall if `.CopyToDataTable()` requries it. Try just `.Select(x=>x).CopyToDataTable();` Did you try trimming out the spaces in your column name? That would have been my first go to btw

Comment: I removed the .Select part from the linq method provided and also tried removing the spaces from the column names but I'm still getting the same order of rows returned

Comment: Do you have an example of the table result you're getting? It's going to be ordering correctly